# Spotlight won't shine on wall

Tags: texturing, lighting

I'm new to Blender and am making a building with spotlights shining on a wall. This worked well until I decided to add an image to the wall texture. Now I can't get the spotlight to shine on the wall. Regardless of how powerful the light is and I've adjusted the light position and texture composition a whole lot. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, for starters, disconnect the image texture from the volume output. If you want a volume, run it through a volume scatter, or a volume absorption shader first, but I don't see why you would want to do that here. Also, you have a shader connected as the input of another shader (the mix shader) - this is not allowed. Just connect the BSDF to the surface output.

Comment: Thanks - I've removed that link from image to volume - not over all change. If I've done something weird here it's because I've be seeking/trying solutions for a few days.

Comment: Strange. Hey, forget what I said before about plugging the shader into the shader. What I meant to say is, connect your image texture to a diffuse shader before connecting it to the mix shader. It came out all wrong... I must be tired As for the rest, I'm not sure. Maybe upload your .blend so others can have a look. I, however, must head to bed, I think.